# How to add a function to an existing list of functions inside an object

Tags: javascript

I'm using the external library and more particularly [LittlePlanet.js](https://pchen66.github.io/panolens.js/docs/panorama_LittlePlanet.js.html):

```js
function LittlePlanet (type = 'image', source) {
    this.dragging = false;
    ...
}

LittlePlanet.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(ImagePanorama.prototype), {
    constructor: LittlePlanet,
    registerMouseEvents: function () {
        this.container.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown.bind(this), {passive: true});
        this.container.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove.bind(this), {passive: true});
        this.container.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp.bind(this), { passive: true});
        ...
    }
});
```

How can I add another event listener to the property `registerMouseEvents` without overriding the preexisting event listeners?

This is what I tried:

```js
PANOLENS.LittlePlanet.prototype.registerMouseEvents = function () {
    zoomOut.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onZoom.bind(this), false);
    ...
};
```

But this overrides the preexisting `registerMouseEvent` event listeners.

Comment: Use monkey-patching. Save the original value of `registerMouseEvents` in a variable, and call that saved function from your replacement function.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show what you tried. You need to use `saved_function.call(this)` so you can pass `this` to the original function.

Comment: It worked with `call()`, thanks!